# Passing const variables to functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, constants

I am learning `TypeScript` and I am a bit confused by the way it handles `const` variables. Let's say I define an interface for a number as:

```
interface MyNumber {
    value: number;
}
```

and created a const `MyNumber`

```
const myNumber: MyNumber = { value: 42 };
```

I read in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) that `const` did not prevent me from modifying the internal state of the object (provided the property is not `readonly`). However, I did not expect this to compile:

```
function setToFive(num: MyNumber) {
    num = {
        value: 5
    }
}

console.log(myNumber);
setToFive(myNumber);
console.log(myNumber);
```

This code prints `42` twice. It looks like the function performs a copy of my `const` variable and uses that copy within its scope. I find this a bit surprising. Is there a way to trigger a `compile-time` error instead?

Comment: you could mark the value field as readonly. That gives you a bit more of protection against accidental assignments.

Comment: Const declaration is not really as immutable as it should be. If a variable holds advanced type ( Object ) you can still change it's properties. Well, if you really want to achieve immutability, you have to use Object.freeze()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reassigning the function parameter ***num*** to your new object. You cannot put const in function parameters.

What you are looking for is eslint or something similar. A tool to force best principles on your project with rule [no param reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.